# %VSINSTALLDIR% in csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, bower

I want to run tools that belong to the VS installation folder from within a .csproj file.

If I run the supplied script:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat
```

then %VSINSTALLDIR% is defined

But inside the .csproj file, it is not defined.

```
<Target Name="RunNpmGulpBower" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec Command="Call &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat&quot; &amp;&amp; npm.cmd install" />
```

This will not work and bower.cmd will not be found.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I've just created an exec command: `<Exec Command="Call &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat&quot; &amp; test.bat" />` where test.bat contains `echo %VSINSTALLDIR%` and as expected it prints `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\`. Can you create a minimal reproduceble example, without npm if possible?

Comment: No bower.cmd anywhere in sight.  People claim that [installing Git is a good idea](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32476/bower-problem-vs-2017.html).

Comment: bower.cmd is now in %VSINSTALLDIR%\Web\External

Comment: @podgorskiy: I followed your example and I managed to make it work; I had tried &nbsp; also %20 for the spaces and various ways to put quotes, but I hadn't tried with &quot;

Comment: however, I found I just shifted the problem :) we have the enterprise edition and external contractors have the community edition and there doesn't seem to be any standard way to make a path to VS' folder

Comment: Instead of specifying the full path, I prefer doing like this: `call %VS140COMNTOOLS%\VsDevCmd.bat` . But unfortunately, this variable is not created by the installer of VS 2017. You may want to look at this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere , it is said that this util is included with the installer.

Comment: I have this variable on 2 servers, but not on my dev VM... thanks a lot for vswhere, that is going to be very helpful!